# SQL - Unknown table X

Tags: mysql, sql

I executed the following SQL:

```
SELECT worker.*
FROM worker w JOIN
     contract c
     ON w.Worker_ID = c.Worker_ID
ORDER BY c.Holidays DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

**Result:** Unknown table 'worker'

If I am using the alias instead, then it works:

```
SELECT w.*
FROM worker w JOIN
     contract c
     ON w.Worker_ID = c.Worker_ID
ORDER BY c.Holidays DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

**Result:**

```
Worker_ID   Name
2           Klink
```

Why does it only work if I am using the alias?

**SQL Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a840b/47

Comment: Why are you setting Alias w and not using it in the first query?

Comment: The alias "renames" the table throughout the query.  It would just be confusing if the same reference had more than one name.

Comment: the whole point of the alias, is to use the alias.  Why are you aliasing it at all if you don't want to use it?

Comment: Because you asked it to use an alias.

Comment: So I am forced to use the alias and can't use the original name?

Comment: if you want to use the original name, don't assign an alias

Comment: Ok now I see how it works. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the alisas `w`

```
SELECT worker.*
FROM worker w JOIN
     contract c
     ON w.Worker_ID = c.Worker_ID
ORDER BY c.Holidays DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Since the table is aliased, in this context, you must use the alias.

Comment: Ok so this means if I am using an alias then I can only access that column via this alias and not with its original name?

Comment: In this case, the table is aliased. Say you wanted to join the table with itself. `select worker.* from worker w1 join worker w2 on w1.Worker_ID = w2.Worker_ID`.. The `worker.*` is ambiguous. This is why you must use the alias.